# Html bullet not appearing as expected

Tags: html, css, angular8

I want to achieve the below screen with html and css in angular 8

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So, `my-component.html` file is as shown below:

And `my-component.scss` is as shown below:

The bullets are appearing square instead of circle. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius

Comment: @vsync yeah, I am able to get a circle now, will have to make the changes to my html and css accordingly. Thanks a lot for the reference. If you want I can accept it as the answer if you post it below :)

Comment: No need, I would rather close this question as a duplicate. Happy to have helped!